# DateTime class as Stopwatch

Tags: c#, datetime

my school project is to make a c# aplication with one button start/stop that starts to count the time and by clicking again stops count the time.
When i use this 3 lines

```
txtVrijeme.Text = Convert.ToString(sada.AddSeconds(i).ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
Thread.Sleep(1000);
i++;
```

without loop (while,for,goto etc.) in forms apk. it works (display 00:00:00, and if i click again 00:00:01) but when I use loop it does not display anything. Why ? btw. console aplication works with this code without any problem(loop in console)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BradičićManuelŠtoperica
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DateTime sada = new DateTime(2009, 6, 22, 0, 0, 0);
        int i = 0;
        bool x = true;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                
        }

        void execute(bool y)
        {

            while (y == true)
             {
                txtVrijeme.Text = Convert.ToString(sada.AddSeconds(i).ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                i++;
            }
        }


        private void btnStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {      
            if (x == false)
                  x = true;    
            else
                  x = false;

            execute(x);
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }    
    }
}
```

[image]

excuse my English :)

Comment: Your logic inside `btnStartStop_Click` can be simplified to `x = !x; execute(x);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, part of the problem is that you're trying to execute a hard loop inside the same thread that's responsible for updating the UI. Instead of using a loop like this, it's better to use a `Timer`, because the timer will run in a different thread so your UI will remain responsive.

The `Timer` has an `Interval` property that defines how often it executes a task. In our case it will be updating the textbox text. I've set this value to 100 milliseconds in the code below. The timer also has a `Tick` event that will execute every time the Interval elapses. Inside this event is where we put the code to update the textbox text.

We should should use a `Stopwatch` to measure elapsed time, because that's what it was built for. The `DateTime` object is great for holding dates, but it's not as accurate for measuring time.

A stopwatch has a `Start` and a `Stop` method that we can call from the button click event, so inside that event all we have to do is first check if the stopwatch is running. If it is, then we Stop it. If it isn't, then we Start it.

Putting these ideas together, your code could look something like this:

```
// At the top of your file, you'll need this to access the Timer:
using System.Windows.Forms;


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    private static readonly Timer Timer = new Timer { Interval = 100 };

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnStartStop.Text = "Start";
        txtVrijeme.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.ff");
        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;  // This hooks up an event handler for the Tick event
    }

    // This code executes every {Timer.Interval} millisecond when the timer is running
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtVrijeme.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.ff");
    }

    // This method handles the button click. It changes the button text and starts
    // or stops the stopwatch, depending on whether the stopwatch is running
    private void btnStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (stopwatch.IsRunning)
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Timer.Stop();
            btnStartStop.Text = "Start";
        }
        else
        {
            Timer.Start();
            stopwatch.Start();
            btnStartStop.Text = "Stop";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*Changing a textbox property does not directly draw anything to the screen.*

Say it again:

*Changing a textbox property does not directly draw anything to the screen.*

What does happen is the Textbox control will invalidate it's graphics area, which will cause a WM_PAINT message to be generated.

The program needs to process this WM_PAINT message before the screen can be updated. The thread that receives and processes your paint events is the **same thread** where your `execute()` method is running. It's also the **same thread** that would handle your `btnStartStop_Click()` method.

Unfortunately, the `execute()` method *never finishes*. It never lets execution on that thread fall back to your program's main message loop, so your program can't repaint the textbox and it can't handle the button click that might finally let the execute() method stop. Even when it pauses, it puts the whole thread to sleep.

What you need to do instead is use a `Timer` component, and handle the Timer's `Tick` event.

Additionally, timer events are not perfectly precise. The slight variance for each Tick event can add up over time, so rather than incrementing the current value for each event your program should remember the start time and compute the difference from the current time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `DateTime` for this.  Instead, create a [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) (in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace).  You won't need to increment it yourself - just start it when the button is clicked, then evaluate its `Elapsed` property to get the duration elapsed (which is a `TimeSpan` type).

Yes, you'll also want a timer to periodically update the display.  That timer can fire as often as you like, and can be imprecise - because it's not responsible for updating the stopwatch, just for writing the current value of the stopwatch to the display.

In summary:

- `DateTime` is for representing a date and time of day.

  - `DateTime.Now`, `DateTime.UtcNow`, etc. give a mechanism to get the current date and time of day.
- `TimeSpan` is for representing durations of elapsed time.

  - `Stopwatch` gives a mechanism for measuring elapsed time.
- Separate the updating of the display from measurement of time.  They are separate concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Your project won't work because you never leave `while`. 
You should try to use Timer.

Read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

I think [this video](https://youtu.be/xFR7WlH21QM) must help you.